# Messed up UVs in Unity3D for Android

Tags: unity, graphics, shaders

All of my quads appear correctly textured on the Unity3D editor, a Motorola Xoom Android tablet, and on an iPad 2:

[image]

But on our Samsung Galaxy Mini 2 smartphone they kinda look like this:

[image]

I wrote a debug shader that outputs the texture coordinates U and V to the R and G channels respectively, and results were consistent:

[image]

What could be causing this difference between devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently I *needed* to assign a vertex color to each vertex of the quad, even when the shader was not using that information. In other words:

```
var colors = new[] {
    Color.white,
    Color.white,
    Color.white,
    Color.white
};
mesh.colors = colors;
```

Assigning these colors solved the UV problem, although I'm not sure why it did.

Comment: Yep, I've had a similar problem with libgdx batch sprites (on all devices). If I didn't asign any color at all to vertices, some quads would display texture normally, some not.